# what permission do I need to copy object between two buckets in two different accounts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am using javascript SDK and a lambda function to copy a file from a source account to the current account where my lambda lives. I'm assuming a role for cross account access to the source account S3 bucket before I call `copyObject` api. But I'm getting Access Denied! Here is my cross account role:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::sourceBucket/*"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

and here is my lambda permissions:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:PutObject"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::destinationbucket/*",
        "Effect": "Allow"
    },
    {
        "Action": [
            "sts:*"
        ],
        "Resource": "*",
        "Effect": "Allow"
    }
]
}
```

I think when I assume the cross account role I give up the lambda permissions and then I cannot copy file to the destination. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You are right, when you assume the cross account role, you lose your current permission. If you want to keep this way of work you need to assume cross account role, copy the file locally to your lambda environment, assume lambda role back and put the file to destination bucket.

Comment: Or you can put all policies into the same role, the one used by lambda, and on bucket put a policy that allow this cross account role to get object from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have:

- A source bucket (`Bucket-A`) in `Account-A`
- A destination bucket (`Bucket-B`) in `Account-B`
- An AWS Lambda function in `Account-B`
- An IAM Role (`Role-A`) in `Account-A` that the Lambda function can assume

Your requirement is to have the Lambda function copy objects from `Bucket-A` to `Bucket-B`.

When using the `CopyObject` command, the credentials must have:

- Read permissions on `Bucket-A`
- Write permissions on `Bucket-B`

However, while `Role-A` does have read permissions on `Bucket-A`, it does not have permission to write to `Bucket-B`.

Therefore, you have two choices:

- **Option 1:** Add a Bucket Policy to `Bucket-B` that grants write permissions to `Role-A`, *or*
- **Option 2:** Instead of using `Role-A`, the administrator of `Bucket-A` in `Account-A` can grant read permissions for `Bucket-A` to the IAM Role being used by the Lambda function by creating a Bucket Policy on `Bucket-A` . That is, the Lambda function *does not* assume `Role-A`. It just uses its own role to read directly from `Bucket-A`.

**Option 2 is better**, because it is involves less moving parts. That is, there is no need to assume a role. I suggest you try this method before using the `AssumeRole` method.

If you do wish to continue with using `Role-A`, then please note that the `CopyObject()` command will need to set the `ACL` to `bucket-owner-full-control`. If this is not done, the `Account-B` will not have permission to access/delete the copied objects. (If you use the second method, then the objects will be copied using `Account-B` credentials, so it is not required.)

**Bottom line:** For your describe scenario involving `Role-A`, **add a Bucket Policy to `Bucket-B` that grants write permissions to `Role-A`**.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I also have the option to assume role A and call getObject() and then assume my lambda role back and call putObject() to make it work. Is there any performance difference to use these two operation instead of single copyObject() operation?

Comment: The `CopyObject()` operation will take place directly between the S3 buckets. This even works between regions! It is much more efficient than doing a download and upload. I suspect it would also copy other information, such as metadata and creation dates. It's much better than downloading and uploading.